# DateTime Parse from PDT

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string which contains a date as shown below

```
string dateTime = "18-Aug-2016 12:02:44 AM PDT";
```

I want it to be converted to the below format

```
Output = 2016-08-18T00:02:44-07:00
```

I tried the below code, but still I need to modify it to get my required output

```
string mydate = dateTime.Replace("PDT", "-0700");
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(mydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateTime = "18-Aug-2016 12:02:44 AM PDT";
string mydate = dateTime.Replace("PDT", "-0700");
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(mydate);
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:O}", dt);
```

Gives me the following output:

```
The current date and time: 2016-08-18T09:02:44.0000000+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if PDT is globally unique, nor if that zone changes during daylight savings time.
Id report back to the Google server team that they are returning something "interesting"